# Generate Incremental ID Based on Matched values In two Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am having some problem regarding generation of incremental ID based on two dataframes. I would like to generate id based on the match department and the current year and month match the last data generated.

Example:

DF1 contains the department name, last id generated and the year and month it was genrated.

[image]

DF2 contains the employee name , The department assigned and this is also where I would genrate the id for that employee.

[image]

As you can see in the DF2 generated id  if it match the current year and month "2002" then I would increment the previous id else I would return the count to 1 .

Here is What I've trie but only on specific cell

```
 # Generate ID, Enco
      DF2= DF2.merge(DF1, on ="Dept",how='left')

      DF2= DF2.reset_index()

      DF2['id'] = DF2.index.astype(int) + startCode

      DF2['Emp ID']=str(YYMM) + "-" + DF2['id'].astype(str)
```

Comment: don't see month in you data

Comment: the month and year is automaticall based on the current date datetime.today().strftime('%y%m')

Comment: Why is `1-2010` not `357-2010` ?

Comment: Because today is 2002 (Feb-2020)already and not 2001 (January-2020). So iwould reset the count to 01

Comment: @kkk - Now understand, so solution working like `356` is replace to `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter per groups and also replace not matched `YYMM` in `Last Count` to `0` for reset counts:

```
yymm = int(pd.Timestamp('now').strftime('%y%m'))

DF2  = DF2.merge(DF1, on ="Dept",how='left')
s = DF2['Last Count'].where(DF2['YYMM'] == yymm, 0)
s1 = DF2.groupby('Dept').cumcount().add(1).add(s).astype(str)
DF2['Emp Id'] = s1 + '-' + DF2['YYMM'].astype(str)
```